# Working with “dual” DNS

Tags: ubuntu, networking, domain-name-system

I'm using Consul as service discovery, and I wish to add it as a DNS server with the current DNS server I have, so when I run dig `ser.service.consul` I will get a result from the consul.

I have tried adding it to `/etc/resolv.conf` but from what I'm seeing it only goes to the first server if it is available and won't go to the secondary DNS if it wasn't found in the first.

Is there any way to use "dual" DNS servers if no address was found in one go to the other?

Comment: One solution would be to setup a DNS forwarder, that would use both your DNSes. For regular queries it would forward requests to regular DNS and for consul to your the DNS servers that correctly resolves these domains.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the relevant configuration in Consul docs:

https://learn.hashicorp.com/consul/security-networking/forwarding

For instance, if you use `dnsmasq` you could add the following line to `dnsmasq.conf`

```
server=/consul/127.0.0.1#8600
```

It basically means that queries to the `consul.` domain and its subdomains
should be resolved by a resolver available at `127.0.0.1:8600`,
which is [a standard location for Consul](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/dns.html).

(And if you need to tweak that, you can find the syntax of the `server=` line in dnsmasq's
[manpage](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html)--search for `-S, --local, --server=`).

Then, after you restart `dnsmasq` (`sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq.service`)
queries to `ser.service.consul` should be resolved by Consul and all other queries
should be resolved as usual.

Comment: Are you sure nothing else is required? I find that .consul domains are not resolved unless I explicitly put `nameserver 127.0.0.1` as the first line in /etc/resolv.conf (which isn't ideal)

Answer (score 0):

Using a dns caching service like 'bind', 'dnsmasq' or 'unbound' is prefered. See 
https://learn.hashicorp.com/consul/security-networking/forwarding#dnsmasq-setup

You can alternatively configure your system to exclusivly use consul for dns, and then provide the [recursors](https://learn.hashicorp.com/consul/security-networking/forwarding#dnsmasq-setup) option in the consul config file which will foward all non `.consul` requests to the appropriate dns server.